# Directxtk SpriteFont blurry when not whole number

Tags: directx-11, blurry, spritefont, directxtk

[image]

The text becomes blurry if I use a non whole number for the position of the string. Any ideas what is causing this and how to correct it?

```
this->pSpriteBatch->Begin();
this->pSpriteFont->DrawString(this->pSpriteBatch, szTempMessage, XMFLOAT2(x, y), color);
this->pSpriteBatch->End();
```

I'm calling it with only the position and color parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`SpriteBatch` renders using `CommonStates::LinearClamp` by default, so it will be blurry if you rendering to a sub-pixel location. You can try using another filtering mode by overriding it with `Begin`:

```
// create an instance of CommonStates as pStates

pSpriteBatch->Begin(SpriteSortMode_Deferred,
    nullptr /*use default blend state */,
    pStates->AnisotropicClamp());
pSpriteFont->DrawString(...);
pSpriteBatch->End();
```

See if that improves your results.